# how to Import woocommerce category images from csv

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how to Import woocommerce category images from csv?

We already have data in CSV, we want to import woo commerce product 
     categories from CSV with images.Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Btw, if i try to search your question [on Google](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C1CAFA_enIT790IT790&ei=TbK0W8DaHMGjkwWizqbICw&q=import+woocommerce+category+images+from+csv&oq=import+woocommerce+category+images+from+csv&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.56082.56210.0.56489.2.2.0.0.0.0.91.178.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.177...35i39k1.0.pfGhvfRkynE) i can found a lot of useful links. Maybe they can help you :)

Comment: This plugin might help you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also struggling to find any plugin etc that works for importing category images. There are plenty of imports for the data, but none include the images. Very strange.

Comment: Try using the WooCommerce Import Export plugin
Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-export-for-woocommerce/

Comment: It looks like the plugin that @SiddharthNagar made might work, but it's $60-$80